# Django: Como agrupar registros utilizando o ANO a partir de um campo FieldDate?

Tags: django

Não estou conseguindo realizar uma consulta que me retorne apenas os "ANOS" que possuem registros!

Considerando ainda que o campo do meu model é um FieldDate.

Comment: Por favor elabore mais a sua pergunta, se possível mostrando qual é seu modelo, onde exatamente quer chegar, o que já tentou fazer, etc. Embora o @Guilherme abaixo tenha conseguido dar uma resposta excelente em face à falta de informações, essa falta de detalhes dificulta muito dar uma resposta satisfatória. "Ajude-nos a te ajudar!" :)

Comment: Por favor coloque exemplos de código e contextualize melhor a pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Django para retornar dados agrupados de parte de uma data (dia, mês, ano, etc) é necessário usar o extra. Exemplo:

```django
compras.extra(select={'month': "DATE_PART('year', data_compra)"}).values('month').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

Comment: Ok. Era isso que eu estava tentando fazer Lucas... Vlw!

Answer (score 2):

Em geral, quando quero retornar algo desse jeito, realizo um select com GROUP BY no campo que preciso.

Algo como:

```sql
SELECT ano FROM registros GROUP BY ano
```

Estes recursos para a construção de queries costumam também estar disponíveis no django.

Comment: Eu não tenho como testar isso no momento, mas dê uma lida sobre agregation e annotation no django, creio que esse [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations) é o que você esteja procurando.

Comment: isso mesmo guilherme!VLW. O @lucas mostrou um exemplo.. e resolveu bastante.

Answer (score 0):

No Django não temos **group by**, mas pensando nesses tipo de caso criamos o **aggregate** e **annotate**[1]

```django
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
>>> pubs
[<Publisher BaloneyPress>, <Publisher SalamiPress>, ...]
>>> pubs[0].num_books
73
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/